# update multi level document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i want to update city = 'kollam' where ref_name='madhan'

```
{
    "company_id": 1,
    "company_name": "amazon",
    "no_of_branc": 2,
    "branch_details": [{
        "branch_id": 101,
        "branch_name": "amazon_pacific_india_zone",
        "sale_detail": {
            "sale_id": 1001,
            "item_name": "dep",
            "amount": 800000,
            "sale_team": "M1",
            "team_detail": [{
                "ref_id": "sc1",
                "ref_name": "radhakrishnan",
                "ref_sal": 8000,
                "ref_address": {
                    "temp_add": {
                        "city": "chennai",
                        "state": "tamilnadu"
                    },
                    "per_add": {
                        "city": "madurai",
                        "state": "pubjab"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "ref_id": "sc2",
                "ref_name": "madhan",
                "ref_sal": 750000,
                "ref_address": {
                    "temp_add": {
                        "city": "banglore",
                        "state": "karnataka"
                    },
                    "per_add": {
                        "city": "vandavasi",
                        "state": "tamilnadu"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "branch_id": 102,
        "branch_name": "amazon_west_zone",
        "sale_detail": {
            "sale_id": 1002,
            "item_name": "sep",
            "amount": 900000,
            "sale_team": "M2",
            "team_detail": [{
                "ref_id": "mc1",
                "ref_name": "pavan",
                "ref_sal": 9000,
                "ref_address": {
                    "temp_add": {
                        "city": "pune",
                        "state": "maharastra"
                    },
                    "per_add": {
                        "city": "delhi",
                        "state": "utterpradesh"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "ref_id": "mc2",
                "ref_name": "chandru",
                "ref_sal": 8500,
                "ref_address": {
                    "temp_add": {
                        "city": "nyc",
                        "state": "tn"
                    },
                    "per_add": {
                        "city": "wdc",
                        "state": "tn"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from doing this?

Comment: @Wellingr Because it's an element in an "array" inside another "array", and there are limitations on what the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) can do. Not that it's a new question.